# Linear regulator to step down voltage from 3.7V to 1.5V

Tags: power, motor, voltage-regulator, charging, lipo

I have a coreless drone motor that connects to power through MCP73833 that connects to a 3.7V LIPO, but the motor is too loud so I want to reduce the speed a little. I figured, the easiest way to do it is to reduce the voltage to the motor. Is it possible to use a linear regulator chip to reduce 3.7V to 1.5V to achieve this goal (reducing RPM).

Maybe use something like LM3670MF-1.5

Comment: Answering your written question: yes, it is possible.

Comment: Perhaps not use the 10 micro Farad inductor (L1)  as shown in (Data sheet) Typical Application: Fixed Output :-)

Comment: depends on motor ESR , L and pole commutation rate i.e. where's your motor spec

Comment: Is the motor directly connected to the battery? Or is there some kind of motor driver in between? While a linear regulator is certainly possible, it is not a good solution, because it will waste a lot of energy in the regulator. It would be way better to use PWM.

Comment: Just to be clear, the term for DC/DC converters such as the LM3670 is "switching", not 'linear' regulator

Comment: If you use a linear regulator, you'll waste more than half your power. A switching regulator is the thing to use for drone flight

Comment: The motor is something like this: https://www.amazon.com/YoungRC-Coreless-Brushed-Propeller-Quadcopter/dp/B078NL9KQQ

Comment: @PaulUszak why not to use the 10 uF L1 inductor?

Comment: It's a poor attempt at a bad joke,  and a cheap shot at the typo. Inductors are not measured in Farads.